# WCF to WCF request and response through MSMQ

Tags: c#, .net, json, wcf, msmq

I have two WCF services :

1.Client WCF Service hosted on IIS configured with REST endpoint facing public returning JSON response.

2.Server WCF Service hosted on IIS configured with SOAP endpoint

and the Client is calling the Server WCF Service to get XML data in response.

As the NetMsmqBinding is one way , how can i integrate MSMQ to acheive the same but with reliability for transactions.

So far i have been able to call from the Client WCF service to the Server WCF service but have not been able to get the return value ,

How to get the response in JSON format ?

Answer (score 0):

As you say MSMQ is one way.

You can have the message Producer to have a reply from the message consumer using a second reply queue.

That way you can have a reply on another queue.

You ll have reliability in transactions when sending OR receiving messages. The two are not coupled.

Regards